# The action of the maximal complex subspace in a toroidal complex Lie group

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, complex-geometry

Let $G:=\mathbb C^n/\Gamma$ be an abelian complex Lie group where $\Gamma$ is a discrete subgroup of $\mathbb C^n$. Suppose $G$ is a **toroidal**  group i.e $G$ contains a normal subgroup $H\cong (\mathbb C^*)^m$ s.t $G/H$ is compact. (Or equivalently $G$ has no non-constant holomorphic functions).

Let $V:=span_\mathbb R\ \Gamma$ and $W:=V\cap iV$ be the maximal complex subspace of $V$. Then the orbit of $W$ through the identity of $G$ is isomorphic to $W/(W\cap \Gamma)$ which is closed and dense in the maximal compact subgroup  $K:=V/\Gamma$ of $G$.

My questions are: Are all orbits of $W$ in $G$  dense in $K$?

Do the orbits of $W$ form a complex foliation of $K$?

Comment: I am confused by your definitions: ${\mathbb C}^*$ admits nonconstant holomorphic functions (the identity map!), but it is a toroidal group according to your main definition. I suspect that you mean that there are no proper holomorphic maps from the complex line to $G$.

Comment: As for your questions: (1) No (unless $G=K$), just take an orbit which contains an element not in $K$. (2) Yes, pretty much just follow the definition of cosets of a subgroup, this holds for any complex Lie group $G$ and complex subgroup $H\le G$.